# Keystonejs V5 search in relationship with GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo-client, keystonejs

I am trying to build a GraphQL query for my keystone server. I want to query inside a relationship. But I can't find anything like that on their GitHub and their documentation.

To manage the thing through T-SQL I would use the following query.

```
SELECT B.*
FROM Book B
LEFT JOIN Author A
ON B.AuthorId = A.AuthorId 
 AND A.LastName LIKE "King"
```

The only thing about relationships I could find is, if an Author is null or not.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: probably not supported, ask on github issues

Answer (score 0):

Using GraphQL Queries you could either get filter Authors and get their books info

```
query {
  allAuthors (where: {
    lastname_contains: 'King'
  }) {
    books {
      id
      ... // data of book you need
    }
  }
}
```

OR

Query Books and use the _some to get a AuthorsWhereInput

```
query {
  allBooks (where {
    authors_some: {
      name_contains: 'King'
    }
  }) {
    id
    ... // data of book you need
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction, can't wait to try this. I'll come back to you :)